# Index/Match Possible Solution?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column on one sheet that needs to bring in data from a matching header column on another sheet.

```
SheetA looks like this:
A              B
ID             2Q 2023 URL
123456         [Formula Here]

Sheet B Looks like this:
A              B              C              D
1Q 2023 ID     1Q 2023 URL    2Q 2023 ID     2Q 2023 URL 
123456         google.com     123456         apple.com
```

So in this case I would need to bring back `apple.com` which is the corresponding URL based on the quarter and the ID.

I would like to use a formula. While I can do this in script I'm not too saavy on using formulas and I can't use a script in this particular situation.

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ger6wumNfcd4Kex-BNabtsQih2pOTZuhCUIp4MipwhQ/edit#gid=2100307022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ain't sure if its just goin' to be a single match OR multiple matches in your real dataset; so test both these out*

```js
=let(Σ,xmatch(B1,'Sheet B'!1:1),
       vlookup(A2,choosecols('Sheet B'!A:D,Σ-1,Σ),2,))
```

*OR*

```js
=let(Σ,xmatch(B1,'Sheet B'!1:1),
       filter(choosecols('Sheet B'!A:D,Σ),choosecols('Sheet B'!A:D,Σ-1)=A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Niether of them are working. First one says vlookup can't find the ID, but it's definitely there. The other one says no matches are found in the filter equation. Also, these columns on sheet B will continue to expand. Is there a way to look at the whole sheet rather than do columns A through D?

Comment: Hopefully someone else will pitch in with a different solution...

Comment: If it helps, there will never be a repeat ID in each colun. So what you have on Column C won't happen. Only Unique IDs in a column. It may show up on another column but never in the same column

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Comment: cool. I had not done that before. I just updated my question to include that sheet.

Comment: I've added the vlookup formula in column_D; Cell_E2 has the same formula reproduced in arrayformula style for ease of use. Also updated the range setting to look for the data in *A-ZZ* (thats like about 702 columns)

Comment: hmm. seems like it's the same formula but it works on this sheet and not on mine. It seems to be stuck on the vlookup. I must be doing something wrong. The only difference betwen the sample file and the actual is that sheet A on the actual file has headers at row 12. but I referenced it to the correct ID. I may need some sleep.

Comment: Alright. I see what I was doing wrong. The ```Σ-1,Σ),2,))``` wasn't working for me because although my sample had the columns side by side, my actual sheet had them separated. Since it was 3 columns before the matched header I changed it to ```Σ-3,Σ),2,))```. Thank you!!

Comment: If I wanted this to be a bit more dynamic, in the event that headerc change positions, how would I replace that minus 1 or minus 3 in my case? another xmatch?

Comment: I replaced the ```Σ-1``` with another xmatch and that did the trick. Wow. It's almost like I understand this now. haha. Thanks again.